# Unable to resize images within portfolio section

Tags: wordpress, web, image-resizing

Our developer has disappeared off the face of the planet and when our web server updated it's PHP version, formerly square images have cropped to landscape.

https://www.weareabsoluteuk.com/retail/

The section in question is the portfolio (screenshot attached) these were previously square but not display landscape despite the featured images still being a 1:1 ratio.

I'm familiar with Divi but this seems to be a custom built slider the developer has made and I'm just trying to figure out how I can make these images display as square again as we've sent countless requests to our developer to no avail

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEYWw.jpg)

Would really appreciate a point in the right direction as I can get the containers to the size they should be but the image never fills them

Thanks

Comment: Change the the code to use thumbnail image. By default thumbnail size is `150px x 150px`. Here is an example image from your site. `https://www.weareabsoluteuk.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Frugi-web-150x150.jpg` Otherwise you need to register your own image sizes and use particular one. I found this article and would be more helpful to you as well. http://nerodev.com/creating-post-thumbnails-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for reply, I can't seem to figure out how to change it though, he's set the slider to pull in .et_portfolio_image but no matter what I do to that I can't seem to get it to display

Answer (score 0):

```
.et_pb_row
```

for this class max-width: 1080px is there, so it is restricting the images to look like rectangle instead of square, and your images are not square

your images are of resolution 400 x 284, so it wont look like square. You can try images as background images in order to appear them as square.

Comment: The image it's pulling in is 600x600 then it's resizing it, I need it to show the original image scale

Comment: Use thumbnail classes. If you need full image URL just use `<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>`

Comment: I don't seem to be able to amend where the slider is pulling the images from so need a way to restyle them via css i think